# Why is it that $\frac{d}{dx}((a+2bx)e^{3x}) \neq \frac{d}{dx}((ae^{3x}+2bxe^{3x}))$

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, associativity

I was computing a differential equation and I ended up with the following result: $\frac{d}{dx}((a+2bx)e^{3x})$. My intuition was to distribute $e^{3x}$, however I got the wrong answer.

When I wrote down both equations into Wolfram Alpha, I got different results.

Why is that the case? Why can't I distribute?

Wolfram alpha:

- [Distributing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5B%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29aPower%5Be%2C3x%5D%2B2bxPower%5Be%2C3x%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D)
- [Not Distributing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5B%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29a%2B2bx%5C%2841%29Power%5Be%2C3x%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice some of the notation Wolfram Alpha is using in the first case:

[image]

It is putting $a'$ and $a''$ and such, even though you presumably meant it as a constant.

That is, Wolfram Alpha is seemingly interpreting $a$ as a function, with argument $e^{3x}$.

Indeed, [editing your input to include an asterisk](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5B%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29a*Power%5Be%2C3x%5D%2B2bxPower%5Be%2C3x%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D), to more explicitly indicate multiplication, seems to fix this.

Comment: @Peter In fact if $a_\text{function}(t)=a_\text{constant}t$ then $a_\text{function}'(e^{3x}) = a_\text{constant}$, that is, the derivative $a'$ that Alpha came up with is equal to the constant $a$ that you wanted, so even with the interpretation of $ae^{3x}$ as a function application you get the right answer (just written in a very misleading way).

Comment: Well this is a relief. Marking as correct!

Comment: Quick question, how come this is different: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=D%5B%5C%2840%29a*Power%5Be%2C3x%5D%5C%2841%29%2BD%5B%5C%2840%29b*2*Power%5Be%2C3x%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D
Isn't derivation distributive with respect to addition?

Comment: It does; WolframAlpha is simply choosing - for whatever reason they prefer - to factor after getting the result. It's not uncommon to see, so you just kind of get used to "well, this looks reasonably close to my answer, so we may as well try to see if my answer is equivalent to Wolfram's."

Answer (score 0):

The first is wrong, Wolfram detect a as a function of x, and used partial differentiation, I recommend using symbolab instead of wolfram.
[image]